# scopes in Active records using lambda - returns No method error in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-activerecord

In my User model class, I have defined 2 scopes as given below.

```
  scope :condition, lambda { where('updated_at >= ?', 3.day.ago) }

  scope :tardy, lambda {
    joins(:timesheets).group("users.id") & Timesheet.condition
  }
```

Then I tried running **reload!**, and thereafter **u =User.find 14** and I got result below.

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 14 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 14, login: "janu", password: "janu", password_confirmation: nil, email: "janu@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-01-03 09:47:36", updated_at: "2013-01-03 09:47:36">
```

Then I run, **u.tardy.to_sql**,but, it returns the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `tardy' for #<User:0x00000003cb5ea0>
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activemodel-3.2.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):64
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

See, When I join both the scopes together as given below, then also I am getting the same error.

```
  scope :tardy, lambda {
    joins(:timesheets).
    where("timesheets.updated_at >= ?", 3.days.ago).
    group("users.id")
  }
```

Can you please help me to resolve the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was on the model's scope definition and meagar's answer is also right for one of the errors.

```
  scope :tardy, lambda {
    joins(:timesheets).group("users.id") && Timesheet.condition
  }
```

In the above, I have specified **Timesheet.condition** where the **condition** scope has to be declared in the **Timesheet model** instead of User model since I need to group the users with respect to the time of timesheet updates. So the below given scope has to be there in the Timesheet model like below.

```
scope :condition, lambda { where('updated_at >= ?', 3.day.ago) }
```

Run **User.tardy**, we will get the **Users** who all are updated their timesheets meeting the condition given.

2nd & Easy way to achieve this is to define a single scope in **User model** itself:

```
scope :tardy, lambda {
    joins(:timesheets).
    where("timesheets.updated_at >= ?", 3.days.ago).
    group("users.id")
  }
```

But, this cross-model scope violates good object-oriented design principles: it
contains the logic for determining whether or not a Timesheet is updated, which
is code that properly belongs in the Timesheet class. So 1st method is preferable.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

You can't invoke a scope on a specific record. When you invoke `.find`, you're getting *one specific record* back, not a relation/association to which additional scopes can be chained.

If you want to find any tardy user with id 14, you'll have to reverse the order of method calls:

```
User.tardy.find(14)
```

You *still* won't be able to run `.to_sql`, as you'll again have a single record. If you really want the SQL back for a specific find-by-id, you could use

```
User.tardy.where(:id => 14).to_sql
```

Comment: I am learning a text book. Please have a look at http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2rMUlUN0Qg8C&pg=PT873&dq=scope+:late,+lambda+%7B+where(%22timesheet.submitted_at+%3C%3D+?%22,+7.days.ago)+%7D&hl=en&sa=X&ei=51fqUNn0MMaNrgeHjoHIDg&sqi=2&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAA